# How to upgrade MySQL to a New version..?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have installed mysql using the package management system.I am using ubuntu machine.

After that i have very well configured the server for InnoDB and other server related parameters.

I am using the version

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------------+
| version()             |
+-----------------------+
| 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1-log |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i want to upgrade my MySQL server to some Higher version say 5.5.
what steps should I follow to accomplish the same...?

Thanks...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa) that someone has created which includes MySQL 5.5.  Since PPA's are community-contributed, the usual warnings about using with caution apply.

There is [a guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) in the MySQL docs for some standard practices to follow when upgrading from one version level to another.

**Edit**:

Here is some information from the [`mysql_upgrade`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html) manual page that should give you an idea of why it's important. This is in response to your comment.

> mysql_upgrade examines all tables in all databases for
>   incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server.
>   mysql_upgrade also upgrades the system tables so that you can take
>   advantage of new privileges or capabilities that might have been
>   added.
>
> mysql_upgrade should be executed each time you upgrade MySQL. It
>   supersedes the older mysql_fix_privilege_tables script, which has been
>   removed in MySQL 5.5.
>
> If mysql_upgrade finds that a table has a possible incompatibility, it
>   performs a table check and, if problems are found, attempts a table
>   repair.

Comment: I am really unable to understand how i will include the PPA.what is the importance of it..??

Comment: what is importance of mysql_upgrade script..??

Comment: @AbdulManaf, see my edit for information on `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: should I use `mysql_upgrade` after `mysqld_safe`? what is the best practice?