# Is there a PPA for MySQL 5.5 for ubuntu 10.10 and 11.10?

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-5.5, ubuntu

I want to install MySQL server 5.5 on ubuntu 10.10 and 11.10 servers but have not yet found a problem free PPA or installation method as of yet. Has anyone managed to do this with the said versions of ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny thing. Someone in another post suggested going to this URL:

https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa

I got that link from this DBA StackExchange post by [@galador](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/695/galador):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9476/877

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. I just tried http://sorok7.blogspot.com/2011/12/install-mysql-5515-on-ubuntu-1110.html and almost succeeded.

Comment: by the way I should mention that this ppa doesn't seem to have it for 10.10, but it works fine for 11.10

Comment: Been a while since this was started but I finally migrated over to using MariaDB and I must say I prefer it.

Comment: I hope my answer was helpful from back in the day. Can I get a +1 please ???